# Why my spring security config not working, how i expected?

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, spring-security

i have a problem...i have the SecurityConfig.class just like this (This is a class that extends of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter):

```
/**
 * This method define which resources are public and which are secured
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))         .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

But my problem is that when i try to access to the SIGN_UP_URL the app is trying to authenticate the user with this filter:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                HttpServletResponse res,
                                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = req.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Access Denied");
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

checking the header that by that point is null (because that URL NOT need theoretically of authentification or any token) this is supposed to not be happening, can someone help me please? when i put the security open for all user without authentification the method is executed succefully

Comment: Do *not* put images of text in SO. 
 Just pasted it here, using the editor. 
 See [ask] and [mcve].  Then read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: ok ok thanks for the advertisement...It's my first post and I did not know those details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add a method in your the SecurityConfig.class

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL);
}
```

in this method you can the urls that you dont like to go to your security filters.